# owl: how to express AllFemaleGame

Tags: owl

AllFemaleGame is a class that corresponds to the class of every game whose players and observers are all women.

**Classes:**

Declaration(Class(ns:Game))

Declaration(Class(ns:Person))

Declaration(Class(ns:Female))

Declaration(Class(ns:Observer))

**SubClasses:**

SubClassOf(ns:Female ns:Person)

**Object Properties:**

ObjectProperty(ns:isPlayerOf)

ObjectPropertyDomain(ns:isPlayerOf ns:Person)

ObjectPropertyRange(ns:isPlayerOf ns:Game)

```
EquivalentClasses(m:AllFemaleGame ObjectIntersectionOf(m:Game ObjectAllValuesFrom(m:isPlayerOf m:Female) ObjectAllValueFrom(m:isObserverOf m:Female)))
```

Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: I understand that "SubClasses: Female of Person" means that Female is a subclass of Person. Why not say it like this, in English, rather than using a pseudo code syntax that nobodies knows? The line with "Object Properties", however, is more cryptic. If you don't know a formal syntax to express what you want, say it in English. The fact that Stack Overflow is mostly for coders does not mean you have to write everything in terms of code! The last piece with "EquivalentClasses" is in valid OWL 2 functional-style syntax, though. Perhaps you could rewrite the rest in that syntax?

Comment: My intuition is that "isPlayerOf(Person) => Game" means that the domain of isPlayerOf is Person, and the range is Game. Or, that if a Person isPlayerOf something, then that thing is a Game. In which case, you have it wrong for the EquivalentClasses part.

Comment: Thanks, edited. I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class expression `ObjectAllValuesFrom(m:isPlayerOf m:Female)` describes the things *x* such that if *x* `m:isPlayerOf` *y*, then *y* is `m:Female`. Moreover, the domain of `m:isPlayerOf` is `m:Person`, and the range is `m:Game`, so if such a *y* existed, then *x* would be a person, and *y* a game. It seems you have it in the wrong direction. Try this:

```
EquivalentClasses(
    m:AllFemaleGame
    ObjectIntersectionOf(
        m:Game
        ObjectAllValuesFrom(ObjectInverseOf(m:isPlayerOf) m:Female)
        ObjectAllValueFrom(ObjectInverseOf(m:isObserverOf) m:Female)
    )
)
```

Note that this class also contains games that do not have players or observers.